# PHP script to delete data from a file server

Tags: php, file, smb

I am struggling to find a way so I could remove files that have been just read by a PHP script. PHP is working on one server, while the files it is reading from are on another server. So far, just to read it I was using SMB server found on git, however function that was supposed to work as deletion (delete a file and the one to delete the directory) got me memory allocation issue(despite all the files have maybe 1MB in total). Permissions are defined by active directory controller, and there is one specific user created just for the purpose of reading those files.
Just in case I will include the git of the smb.
https://github.com/icewind1991/SMB
The user that is being used can create and delete files on the server, doublechecked that.

Comment: You can use https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_delete.asp or a shell_exe with ssh and rm commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you does have access to a remote file-server via SMB-protocol, you can use shell smbclient, by calling it from php.

**First**: install smbclient on your host

**Second**: check if you could run command from terminal manually and remove the file:

`smbclient YOURFILESERVER -c "del /path/to/file/to/remove"`

**Third**: If it's runs ok, than just use php's shell function:

`shell("smbclient $server -c \"del $filename\"")`

(variables $server and $filename should be set of course)